# issue with echo div in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I am doing the login page If the user not successfully login I will use the the below to handle it, which means the message will be showed on the left of text box pwd. But the message never showed when the login failed. Can you tell me why

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<label>Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" size="10"> </br>
<label>Password:</label>
<input type="text" name="pwd"  size="10"> </br>
<?php 
echo '<div style="position:absolute; left:650px; top:25px;float:left">';
if (isset($username))
{
  // if they've tried and failed to log in
  echo 'Your password is not right<br />';
}
echo '</div>';
?>

<a href="index.html">Register</a> &nbsp
<input type=submit name=login value=Login>
</form>
```

If I dont put PHP code, the message will be showed blow the pwd textbox.But I want is to the left of text box. I am sure the problem is CSS style, because when I just define DIV only has one properties, which is float left the error will be showed blow pwd text box, login and register will be to the right of this error message, which is very strange

Comment: Where does `$username` come from?

Comment: if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['pwd']))
{
  // if the user has just tried to log in
  $username = $_POST['name'];
  $password = $_POST['pwd'];

Comment: Well @Shomz's answer is correct. But why are you doing `$username = $_POST['name']; $password = $_POST['pwd'];`?

Comment: style is typo error. I changed it back still don't work

Comment: I will use this to check those two values set or not.If not set, load the whole page, and then after loading the whole page, I will do the check, to see if the user valid or not. The whole code works fun, and only part is that, I want to put the error message besides the pwd box, So I add DIV try to handle it.The problem is that, the div can't work well, if I just remove DIV, the error message will be below pwd box, which I dont want

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using AJAX, and you are not familiar with it. 
Try this!

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<label>Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" size="10"> </br>
<?php 
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['pwd'])){
            $name = trim($_POST['name']);
            $password = trim($_POST['pwd']); # Normally this password is encrypted

            # Database Connection Here 

            if // if they've tried and failed to log in
            {
              echo '<div style="position:absolute; left:650px; top:25px;float:right">Your password is not right<div/>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
<label>Password:</label>
<input type="text" name="pwd"  size="10"> </br>

<a href="index.html">Register</a> &nbsp
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
```

The better solution or practice would be to use AJAX. With AJAX you can display your error message anywhere you want. If you want to practice go to the website link below:-

http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1296